# Void function is throwing a "no return statement" warning

Tags: c, compiler-errors, warnings

So I have the following function, evidently a void:

```
static void *CpuStatsTestLoop (void *arg){
    UNUSED (arg);

    rtems_object_set_name(rtems_task_self(), "CPU Usage Thread");

    while (1)
    {
        sleep (CPU_USAGE_REPORT_INTERVAL_SECS);
        rtems_cpu_usage_report();
        rtems_cpu_usage_reset();
    }  
}
```

and it throws

> "cpu_stats.c:98:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]".

I've tried adding a blank return and return 0 with no luck.

Any idea about why it's throwing this error, and how to fix?

Comment: Your function returns a void*...
static void* cpuStatsTestLoop(...)

Comment: Your function has a return type of a void *. The code expects a void * to be returned

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not a `void` function, this is a `void*` (`void` pointer) function. It must return a value, which must be a pointer to data of any type, or `NULL`.

In your case, a `return` is not necessary, because the function never returns: it has a `while(1)` loop, which runs forever. A better approach is to make it a `void` function, rather than a `void*` function, unless it must conform to some predefined function pointer type.

If changing return type is not an option, for example, because you must pass this function as a `start_routine` parameter of [`pthread_create`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_create.html) you can silence the warning by adding `return NULL` at the end of the function's body.

Comment: _You can also silence the warning by adding return NULL at the end of the function's body._ What for? Deleting of the _"*"_ is much better. Depending the compiler you will get "unreachable code" warning instead.

Comment: @PeterJ It may not be possible, if the function pointer must comply with a pre-defined signature, for example, because you pass this function to `pthread_create`, which is almost certainly the case here.

Comment: This warning is awful because it encourages programmers to change the return type then invoke UB by casting to wrong function type to pass to pthread_create, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much. Returned the return NULL as I'm new to the project and hesitant about changing the types as I will inevitably break something :P

Answer (score 2):

This function has a return type of `void *`, i.e. a pointer of any type, not `void`, so it must return a value.

You could fix this by changing the return type to `void`.  However, it looks like this function is meant to be invoked as a thread, in which case it has to have a signature of `void *(*)(void *)`, so if that's the case changing the return type is not an option.

Given that this function has a `while (1)` loop it should never return.  Still, the function needs to return *something*, so put `return NULL;` at the bottom.  That will satisfy the compiler, and it will act as a safety catch in case you later introduce a bug that causes you to break out of the loop.